# iOS Singleton For Object storage

Tags: ios, singleton

When I first created my app, I stored all my runtime custom objects and properties in my app delegate so I could share them across views.  I never liked this and always wanted to change it so I did some reading today and moved all my runtime properties and objects to a  singleton object like so:

```
@synthesize gblStr;

+(AppDataSingleton *)singleObj
{
    static AppDataSingleton * single=nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!single)
        {
            single = [[AppDataSingleton alloc] init];
        }  
    }    
    return single;
}
```

where lets say gblStr can be accessed from any view controller that has the singleton.

This works great and I now have all my objects stored here instead of in my app delegate.

In each view controller I add the property:

```
AppDataSingleton *globalSingleton;
```

and in the viewDidLoad, I instantiate it:

```
globalSingleton = [AppDataSingleton singleObj];
```

**MY QUESTION IS:**
Will there ever be a case where a user will come back to the app and the singleton has been destroyed? Do I need to check for this?

Or, in the case it was destroyed, will it start the app over from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singleton will be destroyed, if the app has crashes or stops running. Unless you write your objects to a persistent store (CoreData, .plist, SQLite, etc...), you will have to recreate your objects as well...

Comment: I am not worried about it being destroyed if the app crashes or stops running as long as the app starts over.  For example, if I have 4 views A,B,C,D, and I leave the app from view C, when I come right back to the app, everything is fine.  But would the case ever happen where I come back to the app and it loads view C where I left off, but my data in the singleton is gone?

Comment: Most likely, no, but it depends on how you resolve eventual memory warnings.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the singleton should persist for the life of the program run (i.e. an entire session).  If you are not clearing it actively, that data should be there whenever the app returns from an inactive state.  In any case, you are checking if the object is nil and reinstantiating if it is, so the data should be rehydrated.

If you have concerns about data not being there, you should be actively persisting it to CoreData or the sandbox.